# JavaDB vs HSQL vs H2 for testing simple to complex Oracle SQL's

Tags: unit-testing, hsqldb, h2, javadb

DB layer of my product uses MyBatis to execute queries on Oracle database. Wanted to test the DB layer and be able to run the SQLs which are Oracle specific and return the mock data.

From the search I did, I found HSQL having support for Oracle Syntax, does JavaDB support similar feature ? for javaDB, it comes with > java6 so don't need to add more dependency. Which one will be more suitable if my SQL's evolve to use new Oracle specific features etc. I also use Oracle Sequences in my queries.

Why I want to test SQL's ? 
I want to be able to catch logical bugs in SQL's @ development time than in production.

Comment: Do you really want to conduct an open ended discussion of RDBMS virtues here?

Comment: Absolutely No, I have SQL's which are oracle specific, does JavaDB support Oracle Syntax ? and to what level is my question.

Comment: From my point of view, testing with a DBMS that is different to the production DBMS is totally useless.

Comment: See also this (closed) [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2746201/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature comparison request and will probably get closed by moderators.

Does JavaDB support Oracle Syntax? Obviously not. Oracle 10g has several times as many systax features and functions than the latest JavaDB. Does it support a small subset of Oracle Syntax? Yes.

Please read the Guide for these databases and see which one covers the features you need from Oracle Syntax.