# How to vertically align text to the right of some text using javax.swing*;

Tags: java, swing, alignment

How can I align text using Javax.swing. as the numbers are aligned in the pic:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to make a receipt which aligns item's prices](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39650927/418556)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with using HTML and JLabel. It allows you to insert tabulators in your text. To make them visible you have to use `<pre></pre>` tags. Consider this code, hope it helps.

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    JLabel text;

    public Main() {
        String html = "<html><pre>xxxx\t\txxxx<br>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\txxxx</pre></html>";
        text = new JLabel(html);
        text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));

        add(text);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"It allows you to insert tabulators in your text."* Better if using HTML would be a `table` structure. Tabs could be used in a `JTextArea` using a monospaced font.

Comment: Good notice but I think tabs should work not only with monospaced fonts.