# Developing Java Swing Application that will use a database to store data and display it on the JFrame

Tags: java, mysql, database, windows, swing

Good day, I have a potentially easy question. I am in the process of developing an application for my mother. She teaches a Sunday-school class, has been teaching it for many years now, and as you can guess, has a ton of information kept hard copy. She also has complex grading styles, a store where kids can buy stuff with their good grade points (called talents).

Anyway, I come from a background where I used a database to store massive amounts of information, but the database was always static. Meaning I would open MySQL, add an instance of our local DB, and then just connect to it whenever I need to. But the problem arises, how do I distribute an application that exists statically (ie you have to put all connection details into the program) be flexible enough to where I can install my App onto any computer and it would work without a specific database connection. In other words, is there a lightweight database that can be attached to a program that will be distributed?

I don't want to store information like Students in an array list, I am bent on using a database, unless someone can convince me. (also because with a database, it is easier to make the data persistent, it seems to me)

**SO the question again, how do I develop an application that will use a database, but will also exist when you distribute the application to other computers without having a network database that has to be connected to every time the app is run?**

I'm sorry if it is a basic question, I come from an HMI/SCADA background, things work a little differently...

Comment: See also  [*Which is better H2 or HSQLDB?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2746201/230513) and [*Frontend tool to manage H2 database*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2760887/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use H2. It is a Java database.
http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Comment: So they are called embedded DB's, huh? Thanks for the quick reply...